# Change axis labels with matplot in R

Tags: r, axis-labels

I'm trying to change the x axis in a `matplot`, but this command doesn't work:

```
TimePoints=1997:2011
matplot(t(DataMatrix),type='l',col="black",lwd=1,xlab="Anni",ylab="Rifiuti",main="Produzione rifiuti")
axis(side=1,at=TimePoints,labels=TimePoints)
```

with `plot` I used this without problems. How can I fix it?
Here you can find the objects: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47720440/SOF.RData

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually do this as follows:

1. Omit the axes altogether.
2. Add the axes with desired options one by one.

In R:

```
# Add argument axes=F to omit the axes
matplot(t(DataMatrix),type='l',col="black",lwd=1,xlab="Anni",ylab="Rifiuti",main="Produzione rifiuti",axes=F)

# Add Y-axis as is
axis(2)

# Add X-axis
# Note that your X-axis range is not in years but in the "column numbers",
# i.e. the X-axis range runs from 1 to 15 (the number of columns in your matrix)
# Possibly that's why your original code example did not work as expected?
axis(side=1,at=1:ncol(DataMatrix),labels=TimePoints)
```

Comment: For those new to R, I would like to point out that the length of "at" must be equal to the length of "labels".