# Matplot R manually labelling x-axis

Tags: r, axis-labels

I have a problem labelling my matplot x-axis row. So I have 1388 instances, but I want my X-axis to a custom labeling in the form of a sequence in dates.
My R code looks like this:

```
Dates <- seq(as.Date("2004/01/29"), as.Date("2009/07/31"), by = "quarter")

matplot(seq(1388), t(Alldata[1, ]), type = "l", 
    lwd = 1, lty = 1, col = 1:10, xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Strike", 
    main = paste("TEST"), xaxt='n')
axis(side = 1:23, at=1, labels = paste(Dates, 1:23))
```

Can anybody help me get the Dates into the x-axis?
I have tried using same method as this: [Change axis labels with matplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253659/change-axis-labels-with-matplot-in-r)
but it doesn't work.
AllData is from an excel file in which the first number of rows looks like this:
[image]

Comment: (`object 'Alldata' not found` ... can you make this question reproducible?)

Comment: What is Alldata?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, the Alldata is loaded from an excell file with 1388 instances, I've taken a screenshot of the first rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have confused the way the function `axis` works.  In answering below I will generate a random matrix to replace your `Alldata` which I don't have access to

```r
Alldata <- t(as.matrix(rnorm(23)))
```

We can generate the plot again:

```r
matplot(seq(23),  Alldata[1, ], type = "l", 
        lwd = 1, lty = 1, col = 1:10, xlab = "Dates", 
        ylab = "Strike", main = paste("TEST"), xaxt='n')
```

Now, its import to know what the arguments to `axis` are. First
`side` this is literally the side of the the rectangle on which the plot is drawn. It is one of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 corresponding to bottom, left, top, right, respectively.

You want the axis to be on the bottom so we set this to 1.

Next, the `at` argument, is for where the tick marks should be drawn. So if you have 10 points on your line, and you set this value to `1:10` it will draw a tick mark at each point on the axis. If you set it to c(2,4,6,8,10) it will draw a mark at every second point on the axis. In your case you've set it to 1, which would draw only one tick. Although since the `side` was set to 1:23 none showed up.

`labels` This argument will label the ticks which are drawn. Ideally it should be a vector the same length as the `at` value.  You can make sure that they are the same length by creating an index variable and using this as the `at` variable and to index the labels.

This gets us to:

```r
index <- c(1,7,14,21)
axis(side = 1, at = index, labels = paste(Dates, 1:23)[index])
```

I think having a full range of dates would look cluttered. But you can drop the index and choose the below if you prefer:

```r
axis(side = 1, at = 1:23, labels = paste(Dates, 1:23))
```